# How to append text in textarea having existing text in it

Tags: automation, sendkeys, web-testing

This is my current code

```
WebElement textarea_click = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gvPods_txt_Comment_" + i + "\" ]"));
                        
             textarea_click.click();
             Thread.sleep(15000);
System.out.println("Text area is open");

                        
textarea_click.append = ("XWC status is NOGO");

Thread.sleep(2000);`
```

I intend to append the value of `textarea_click`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the `textarea` via

```
textarea_click.getAttribute("value")
```

And you can append the value via

```
setAttribute(textarea_click,"value",textarea.getAttribute("value") + "XWC status is NOGO");
```

Sources:

https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/3803119/get-value-from-textfield-textarea-using-selenium
https://groups.google.com/g/selenium-users/c/3J27G1GxCa8?pli=1

Comment: This didn't worked.I tried in below manner                                                                              WebElement textarea_click = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gvPods_txt_Comment_" + i + "\" ]"));
driver.findElement(By.name("gvPods$ctl10$txt_Comment" ));
                                                textarea_click.click();
      Thread.sleep(15000);
      System.out.println("Text area is open");

      
textarea_click.getAttribute("value");

setAttribute(textarea_click, "value",textarea_click.getAttribute("value") + " XWC is NOGO");

Comment: @TejashreeVeer can you elaborate on how did it fail? Did you get an error?

Comment: i don't get any error. But i don't see the result also. The value which i want to add to the value already present in textarea is not getting added.